# How to configure a 1-to-1 relation between two entities, with one being the principal?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and the fluent API for configuring bindings. My two entities look like this:

```
public class Matter
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Primary key
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation: the most recent Relativity activity for the Matter
    /// </summary>
    public virtual RelativityActivity RelativityRecentActivity { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class RelativityActivity
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Primary key
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Foreign key: the Matter that the Relativity Activity entry is associated with
    /// </summary>
    public Matter Matter { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

I'm working with an existing table schema, and in the schema the `RelativityActivity` table simply has a foreign key to `Matter`'s `Id` column. So, `Matter` is the principal in the relation and can exist without a `RelativityActivity`. A `RelativityActivity` cannot exist without a `Matter`, though.

For the life of me, I cannot seem to configure this to work as I expect. I've read tons of answers on SO, and I adjust my fluent API bindings after reading each one, but I always seem to get errors ranging from "cant determine principal end of relation", to "you have configured it with incorrect multiplicities".

My current fluent API bindings look like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RelativityActivity>().HasRequired(m => m.Matter).WithRequiredDependent(m => m.RelativityRecentActivity).Map(m => m.MapKey("matter")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

for the `RelativityActivity`, and:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Matter>().HasOptional(m => m.RelativityRecentActivity).WithRequired(m => m.Matter);
```

for the `Matter`.

I have two bindings in the relation, because without the `Matter` binding I was getting unable to determine principal end error. But now I get an error about multiplicity.

Edit for clarification:

The foreign key column, in `RelativityActivity` table, is not the `Id` column. It is actually another column named `matter`. I try to specify this using the `Map` function in my binding.

Comment: Is `RelativityActivity.Id` the foreign key in the relationship, or is there a second field such as `RelativityActivity.MatterId` in the `RelativityActivity` table that is the foreign key? This may well "matter" to the answer.

Comment: No, the foreign key column is actually another column in the table, named "matter". In my binding I am using `Map` to specify that, I think. That is my intention anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db schema can only enforce a `0..1 - n` association. A `1:1` association always involves either two mutually referring foreign keys, or a primary key that at the same time is a foreign key to another primary key.

You can model a 1:1 association the way you do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Matter>().HasOptional(m => m.RelativityRecentActivity)
                             .WithRequired(m => m.Matter);
```

The problem is that EF will assume that the database schema also accommodates 1:1 associations.

If you want to save a `Matter` and an `RelativityRecentActivity` object, EF will insert a `Matter` record and take its PK value to use it as PK for the `RelativityRecentActivity` (assuming that it's also a FK). So in your case the real foreign key field is never filled. Besides that, it may also raise exceptions if `RelativityRecentActivity` has an auto-incrementing PK (identity column in Sql Server).

So I think you can only model the association as a regular 1-many association and use business rules to enforce that "many" is never more than 1:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Matter>().HasMany(m => m.RelativityRecentActivity)
            .WithRequired(r => r.Matter)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("matter");
```

Comment: So if I were able to adjust the schema to have `RelativityActivity`'s FK to `Matter` also become the table's PK, then my binding logic would work for EF?

Comment: Sure, if you can change the schema you can make your mapping work the way you'd want it. Maybe the easiest way is to see how EF creates a database with the mapping you choose and copy that in the existing database.

Comment: Thank you. I think adjusting the schema has allowed this to work. Either that or the way you worded it! Thanks.